# Add Extra Count When Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have simple reservation form,  in a main input type text . that i show the final result of each select box on it. my problem is when i select 2 room . the number of adult changes to 2 , while i never choose 2 adult and i can not change this value in input type text. if you change the value of room count to 2. you can see the value of adult changes too. and it is not correct.
here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  
  $('body').on('change', 'select', function(){
   
var rcount = $('select[name*=roomCount]').toArray().reduce(function(prev, current){
  prev += parseInt($(current).val());
  return prev;
},0);

var acount = $('select[name*=adultcount]').toArray().reduce(function(prev, current){
  prev += parseInt($(current).val());
  return prev;
},0);

var ccount = $('.childcount').toArray().reduce(function(prev, current){
  prev += parseInt($(current).val());
  return prev;
},0);

$('#allcount').val('room:'+rcount+'adult:'+acount+' child:'+ccount);
});
  $("#roomCount").change(function() {
    //
  
    countRoom = $(this).val();
    $(".numberTravelers").empty()
    for (i = 1; i <= countRoom; i++) {
      $(".numberTravelers").css("width", "100%").append('<div class="countRoom"><div class="numberOfRooms">room</div> <div class="inner-items" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 49%;"><div class="title-item">adult</div><select name="_root.rooms__' + i + '.adultcount"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select></div><div class="inner-items style="width: 49%;""><div class="title-item">child(</div><select name="childcount" class="childcount" onchange="childAge(this)"><option value="0"> 0 </option><option value="1"> 1 </option> <option value="2"> 2 </option><option value="3"> 3 </option><option value="4"> 4 </option></select></div><div class="selectAge"></div><input type="hidden" name="_root.rooms__' + i + '.childcountandage" class="childcountandage"/></div><div class="clr"></div>')

    }
  });

  $(".submit").click(function() {
    $(".countRoom").each(function(index, element) {
      var childCount = $(this).find(".childcount").val();

      var childAge = " ";
      $(this).find(".childage").each(function(index, element) {
        childAge = childAge + ',' + $(this).val();
      });
      //childAge=childAge.substring(0,childAge.length - 1);
      $(this).find(".childcountandage").val(childCount + childAge);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="allcount" value="room:1 ,adult:1 , child :1" />
<div class="title-item">room count</div>
<select name="roomCount" id="roomCount">
<option value="1" class="btn2"> 1 </option>
<option value="2" class="btn2"> 2 </option>
</select>

<div class="numberTravelers">
  <div class="countRoom">
    <div class="inner-items" style="margin-left: 5px;">
      <div class="title-item">adult</div>
      <select name="_root.rooms__1.adultcount">
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-items">
      <div class="title-item">Child</div>
      <select name="childcount" class="childcount" onChange="childAge(this)">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="selectAge"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_root.rooms__1.childcountandage" class="childcountandage" />
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Issue is inherent to your design. You *either* need to add a `0` option for number of `adults` or give a *checkbox* option for user to either take one *room* or the other.

Comment: @gurvinder372 o option for adult is not possible. how can i Keep 1 adult even when i choose 2 room ?

Comment: You need to make user add and confirm the room before adding it to the main tally. This is more of a design issue than code issue.

Comment: @gurvinder372 i don't get it:(

Comment: You are getting 2 because you are capturing change even for the adult count dropdown. As soon as new adult dropdown, its value is considered for adding to the total tally.

Comment: @gurvinder372 how can i solve this problem without change the code?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by - *how can i solve this problem without change the code*. You need to be clear about requirement first - Do you want the user to be able to select add a room to total tally without confirmation? What if user has changed the value to 1 later, etc. Given the way problem is defined as of now, I can't think of a straightforward solution to this without changing the design.

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes actually i want to add a room total without any confirmation. i want to add a room and not change the value to 2. and 2 still remain one till the user changes the value of adult to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had create some sample, i not sure what is this `childAge` as the sample did not include on it, hopefully this give you some idea on how it work, attached is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pq1qhggu/3/

the issue here is due to the fire event on body change, hence all the select is being fired at the same time, so i adding a kinda hardcoded name check, if name is the same, then do a calculation

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $name = $this.attr('name');

  if ($name === 'roomCount'){
        rCount = $this.toArray().reduce(function(prev, current){
                    prev += parseInt($(current).val());
                    return prev;
                  },0);
  }else if ($name === '_root.rooms__1.adultcount'){
        aCount = $this.toArray().reduce(function(prev, current){
                    prev += parseInt($(current).val());
                    return prev;
                  },0);
  }else if ($name === 'childcount'){
        cCount = $this.toArray().reduce(function(prev, current){
                    prev += parseInt($(current).val());
                    return prev;
                  },0);
  }
 $('#allcount').val('room:'+rCount+'adult:'+aCount+' child:'+cCount);
});
```

and i also change from

```
$("#roomcount")
```

to

```
$("#allcount")
```

not sure why you only fired when `roomcount` is change instead of the `allcount`?